# How to iterate over distinct dates in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have the following table:

| id | date | gap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-01-01 | 3 |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | 8 |
| 4 | 2020-01-02 | 6 |
| 5 | 2020-01-02 | 10 |
| 6 | 2020-01-02 | 12 |

I want to iterate over the distinct dates and fetch the two rows with the highest "gap" value. Desired result:

| id | date | gap |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 2020-01-01 | 5 |
| 3 | 2020-01-01 | 8 |
| 5 | 2020-01-02 | 10 |
| 6 | 2020-01-02 | 12 |

I have attempted the following

```
DO $$
DECLARE
    temprow record;
BEGIN
FOR temprow in
        SELECT DISTINCT date 
        FROM table
    LOOP
        SELECT *
        FROM table
        ORDER BY gap DESC
        LIMIT 2;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Giving me the following error:

> ERROR:  query has no destination for result data.

Wrapping the last SELECT statement with a RETURN() gives:

> ERROR:  RETURN cannot have a parameter in function returning void

I am not sure if I even need a loop for this, so feel free to suggest a solution without a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using window functions:

```
select id, "date", gap
from (
  select id, "date", gap, 
         dense_rank() over (partition by "date" order by gap desc) as rnk
  from the_table
) t
where rnk <= 2
order by "date", gap;
```

If there are two rows with the same (highest) gap on the same date, both will be returned. If you don't want that, use `row_number()` instead of `dense_rank()`

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e68e6edfb8e4e435b9549f65d6b505a9)

Comment: Yep, `DENSE_RANK`, `RANK`, and `ROW_NUMBER` are all valid options, depending on how the OP wants ties to be dealt with.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a loop nor plpgsql for this.

```sql
select l.* from 
(
 select distinct "date" as dd from the_table
) t 
cross join lateral
(
 select * from the_table 
 where "date" = t.dd order by gap desc limit 2
) l
order by "date", gap;
```

Almost in plain language - for every distinct date `dd` fetch two rows.

Comment: Yep, being able to express what you want selected in almost plain English is a strength of SQL. I still like the window approach better, although the English sounds a tad more long-winded "rank the rows per date by gap, then keep all top-two rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I agree, ranking gives you better control.